# ADO.NET + T-SQL Invoke scalar function from another DB?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

I have an SQL script `select [master].[dbo].sp_SearchDuplicatedAddress('','','','')` that I can invoke successfully from management studio. The function `sp_SearchDuplicatedAddress` exists in master database and is accessible by the logged user, no problem here. The problem arises when I try to execute that SQL script from ADO.Net I get the following error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Cannot find either column "master" or the user-defined function or aggregate "master.dbo.sp_SearchDuplicatedAddress", or the name is ambiguous.'
```

And here's the code of sample app:

```
    var conn = new SqlConnection();
    var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "select [master].[dbo].sp_SearchDuplicatedAddress('','','','')";
    conn.Open();
    var outt = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Any idea how can I execute cross database queries from ADO.Net?

Comment: Do you specify connection string?

Answer (score 0):

No repro for me.  Can you modify the below to reproduce the behavior?

```
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using System;

namespace SqlClientTest
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var constr = "server=localhost;database=master;integrated security=true";

            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = @"
create or alter function dbo.sp_SearchDuplicatedAddress ( @a varchar(20),@b varchar(20),@c varchar(20),@d varchar(20) )
returns int
as
begin 
 return 3;
end ";
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }

            constr = "server=localhost;database=tempdb;integrated security=true";
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "select [master].[dbo].sp_SearchDuplicatedAddress('','','','')";
                conn.Open();
                var outt = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                Console.WriteLine(outt);

            }

        }
    }

}
```